# Get a File or URI object for a file inside an archive with Java?

Tags: java, file, uri, archive

is it possible to get a File or URI object for a file inside an archive with Java?
(zip or jar archive)

Thanks Hemeroc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `jar:` protocol is a way to build a URI to a resource in a JAR archive:

```
jar:http://www.example.com/bar/baz.jar!/path/to/file
```

See the API docs for JarURLConnection: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html

Between the `jar:` and `!/` can be any URL, including a `file:` URL.

Answer (score 2):

```
public List<File> getFilesInJar(String jarName){    
  List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
  File jarFile = new File(jarName);    
  JarInputStream jarFile = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream(jarFile));
  JarEntry jarEntry;

  while ((jarEntry = jarFile.getNextJarEntry()) != null) {
    result.add(inputStreamToFile(jarFile.getInputStream(jarEntry)));
  }
  return result;
}
```

for the inputStreamToFile method, google "java inputStream to file", although you might be happy with an InputStream object also, instead of a File object :)

Answer (score 1):

For the actual file data, see [ZipFile#getInputStream(ZipEntry)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#getInputStream%28java.util.zip.ZipEntry%29). The javadocs for that class explain how it is to be used.